# Reverse for 'entrypage' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
VIEWS.PY
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
import markdown2

from . import util

class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Tell us more!"
        })
    )


def add_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        entries = util.list_entries()
    
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        
        for entry in entries:
            if title.upper() == entry.upper():
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/errorpage.html")
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('encyclopedia:entrypage'))
else:
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/addpage.html", {
        "form": AddPageForm()
    })
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name="entrypage"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
]
```

ADDPAGE.HTML

```
        <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:addpage' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
```

LAYOUT.HTML

```
                <div>
                <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:addpage' %}">Create New Page</a>
            </div>
            <div>
```

I have tried updating the urls and the views to this but i keep getting error responses

```
    path("add_page/<str:title>", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    def add_page(request, title):
```

Please advise where this error response could be coming from as the above edits is what i saw in some other stackoverflow responses to clear the error but this didn't work for me.

Thank you

Comment: Show us the entry_page view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a redirect to `entrypage`, you need to specify the title, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def add_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        entries = util.list_entries()
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
        
            for entry in entries:
                if title.upper() == entry.upper():
                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/errorpage.html")
            #                                   specify title ↓
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title=title)
    # …
```

I would also strongly advise to make use of a database, and *not* fetch all entries from the utility: a database is optimized to search effective, whereas accessing the list of files takes linear time to search. If you define a database model, you can add [**`db_index=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) to build an index which can boost searching enormously.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am fetching entries from util because this is an assignment and it was already provided for us to work with by CS50W. I tried this and it worked. Ok, Im excited so a big thank you from me to you. Could you please expalin why this didnt work with  HttpResponseRedirect (reverse). Also, should we always specify titles while using redirects.

Comment: When Django use the reverse method is trying to get your url with the arguments you have provided in your view, in your case you add the **title** argument but you forgot to specify it in your **redirect**, Django could not find any url matching your reverse match, see here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#module-django.urls

Comment: @Chuks: `redirect` is a "shortcut", it calls `reverse` and will then wrap the result in a `HttpResponseRedirect`. It is thus a bit more elegant.

Comment: @Chuks: I recently wrote an article about the difference between the two: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/difference-between/reverse-redirect.html